# Does the converse of Krull’s principal ideal theorem hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Can we prove the converse of Krull’s principle ideal theorem in the case when $R$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$?

To be more precise, can we prove the following statement:
In the above case, when $P$ is a prime ideal with height 1 in $R$, then $P$ contains a non zero-divisor?

@Mohan has shown in the comment that the statement above doesn’t hold for some case.

So I want to change the condition for ring $R$ to be finitely generated free $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Does the statement holdin this case?

Comment: Try $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2,xp)$ where $p$ is any prime number and $P=(x,p)$.

Comment: @Mohan Yes, I think you are right. It’s a good example.

Comment: In the case when $R$ is a free abelian group, what you say is true. $P\cap\mathbb{Z}\neq 0$ and so generated by a prime number $p$ and then $p$ is a non-zero divisor by your assumption.

Comment: @Mohan Can you show me in detail why $P\cap \mathbb{Z}\neq 0$. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Since $R$ is a finitely generated module over the integers, its dimension is at most 1 and thus a height one prime is maximal. If the map $\mathbb{Z}\to R/P$ is injective, since the latter is a field, this will factor through $\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Q}\to R/P$ and then $R/P$ is not a finitely generated abelian group.

Comment: @Mohan I think we can get the result that $P\cap mathbb{Z}\neq$ by using the fact that $R$ is integral over integers which deduce the incomparablity.